# Add Custom ValidationAttribute to Swagger Documentation

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, validationattribute

I have a custom validation attribute

Lets say I have a HelloWorld class that implements ValidationAttribute. I then apply this attribute to a field within my API.

```
[HelloWorld]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

When I generate the Swagger UI, I get a JSON OpenAPI spec and the model displays the properties of each field like below:

[image]

If I add a Required tag, a asterisk is displayed
If I use attributes like RegularExpression/Range/StringLength, text appears to specify this.
However, I would like to make someone aware of the custom validation, with my own description.

Is it possible?

Any help would be much appreciated. I've spent all day looking at DocumentFilter/SchemaFilter/OperationFilter, but can't find any good documentation or examples.

Comment: OpenAPI Specification supports `x-` [extensions](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/openapi-extensions/) to specify custom metadata. The library that you use to generate the API definition from code (Swashbuckle? Swagger-Net?) probably provides a way to define `x-` extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use OperationFilter, but it wasn't supported on .Net Framework 4.1.

I would have to use the filters to amend the documentation (I believe this is the was x-extensions is utilised)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

1. Create custom validation attribute, for example UniqueAttribute

   ```
   public class UniqueAttribute : ValidationAttribute { ... }
   ```
2. Apply this attribute to a model property

   ```
   [Unique]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   ```
3. Implement ISchemaFilter interface extension

   ```
   public class AddUniquenessDescriptionFilter : ISchemaFilter
   {
     public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
     {
       var attr = context.MemberInfo?.CustomAttributes.Where(x => 
            x.AttributeType.Name == nameof(UniqueAttribute)) 
            .FirstOrDefault();

       if (attr is not null)
       {
         schema.Extensions.Add("isUnique", new OpenApiBoolean(true));
       }
     }
   }
   ```
4. And use extension on startup

   ```
   builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => 
   { 
     options.SchemaFilter<AddUniquenessDescriptionFilter>(); 
   });
   ```

The results look like this:
[Swagger documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPpIW.png)

Here is a full example: [Custom ValidationAttribute](https://github.com/AlbertSh22/RoboSvc/tree/master/src/PublicApi)